# Problema com Celery e Django/Python

Tags: python, django, task

Estou tentando implementar um sistema de tasks com Celery no Django, mas está dando erro e eu não sei como resolver...

Erro que aparece no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task

from datetime import date



@task(ignore_result=True)
def verify_post_date(string):
    print(string)
```

**settings.py**

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta


CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {

    'verify_post_date': {
        'task': 'core.verify_post_date',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),

    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua task recebe um parâmetro 'string'. Logo, para agendá-la, você deve passar este parâmetro através da chave 'args', conforme abaixo:

```
'verify_post_date': {
    'task': 'core.verify_post_date',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
    'args': ('teste')
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.